# How to implement 'Comparable' if parent class already has a '=='

Tags: ruby

I have a library class, which provides methods for equality and inequality. I'm deriving another class from this, which, differently from the parent class, introduces an *ordering relation*, i.e. it would make sense to ask for two elements of the derived class, which one is smaller. In particular, arrays of objects of the derived class can be sorted.

My first approach was

```
class MyClass < LibraryClass
  def <(other)
    ...
  end
  def <=>(other)
    return 0 if self == other
    return -1 if self < other
    return 1
  end
  # code for operators > <= >= is not shown here....
end
```

This seems to work, but I thought that it may be better to instead [sic] `Comparable`, since this would give plenty of other methods for free.

1. The description of `Comparable` says that I have to implement the `<=>` operator, and other operators including `==` and `!=` would then be automatically implemented. However, I am already happy with the `==` operator from the parent class, so no new method for equality should be generated.
2. I want to test for equality using the `==` operator from the parent class. If I implement the `<=>` operator, and `Comparable` implements an `==` operator in terms of my `<=>` operator, I would end up in a recursive call.

For expression `self == other`, how can I specify that the `==` operator of the parent class should be invoked?

Comment: Why do you refuse the Ruby way? Just follow what the document says.

Comment: Why does it end up in recursive call? Can you clarify that?

Comment: @sawa : Because in my setup, my <=> would invoke ==, which is the == of Comparable, which then would again call my <=>. But thanks to the concise solution posted by JörgWMittag, and the excellent tutorial posted by CarySwoveland, I see now how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `include` makes `Comparable` the superclass of `MyClass` and `LibraryClass` the superclass of `Comparable`. So, the implementation of `==` in `Comparable` overrides the implementation of `==` in `LibraryClass`.

What you can then do, is to override `==` *again* in `MyClass` with a version that is identical to the one in `LibraryClass`:

```
class MyClass < LibraryClass
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    # whatever
  end

  define_method(:==, LibraryClass.public_instance_method(:==))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a subclass of Range that overwrites `Range#==`.

```
class OddRange < Range
  def ==(other)
    !super
  end
end

OddRange.new(1, 10) == OddRange.new(2, 7)
  #=> true
```

Note that

```
OddRange.included_modules
  #=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

which does not include `Comparable`. Now let's create a subclass of `OddRange` and examine it's behaviour.

```
class MyRange < OddRange
end

MyRange.ancestors
  #=> [OddRange, Range, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
MyRange.instance_method(:==).owner
  #=> OddRange 
rng1 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng2 = MyRange.new(2, 4)
rng3 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng1 == rng2
  #=> true 
rng1 == rng3
  #=> false
```

We next `include` the module `Comparable` into `MyRange`, and add an instance method to `MyRange`<sup>1</sup>.

```
class MyRange
  def <=>(other)
    self.end <=> other.end
  end
  include Comparable
end

MyRange.ancestors
  #=> [MyRange, MyComparable, OddRange, Range, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
MyRange.instance_method(:==).owner
  #=> Comparable 

rng1 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng2 = MyRange.new(2, 4)
rng3 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng1 == rng2
  #=> false
rng1 == rng3
  #=> true
rng1 <=> rng2
  #=> 1
```

No surprises.

If we don't want `Comparable#==` to overwrite `MyRange#==`, we could do the following.

```
class MyRange
  def ==(other)
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.call(other)  
  end
end
```

This "jumps over" `Comparable` and uses `OddRange`'s method `:==`. See [Method#super_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method).

```
rng1 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng2 = MyRange.new(2, 4)
rng3 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng1 == rng2
  #=> true
rng1 == rng3
  #=> false
```

Now let's add another instance method to `OddRange`.

```
class OddRange
  def :<=(other)
    (self.begin <=> self.begin) <= 0
  end
end

rng1 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng2 = MyRange.new(2, 4)
rng1 <= rng2
  #=> false
```

We see that `Comparable#<=` and `MyRange#<>` cause `rng1 <= rng2` to return `false`. If we wished to instead use `OddRange#<=`, we could of course do what we did before, add

```
 def <=(other)
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.call(other)  
 end
```

to `MyRange`. More generally, if we don't want `Comparable` instance methods to overwrite *any* `OddRange` instance methods (which may change over time), we could do the following.

```
class MyRange
  (instance_methods & OddRange.instance_methods(false)).each do |m|
    define_method(m) do |other|
      method(__method__).super_method.super_method.call(other)  
    end
  end
end

rng1 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng2 = MyRange.new(2, 4)
rng3 = MyRange.new(1, 5)
rng1 == rng2
  #=> true
rng1 == rng3
  #=> false
rng1 <= rng3
  #=> true
```

<sup>1 Redefining `rng1`, `rng2` and `rng3` below isn't actually necessary.</sup>